# Does the hag's desiccated dwarf head grant darkvision?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

In Volo's Guide to Monsters, one of the items presented as loot from a hag is "The leathery, preserved head of a dwarf. Anyone who holds its 5-foot-long beard can see through its eyes."

Would holding the beard give the holder darkvision through the dwarf's eyes?

Answer (score 2):

It only says you can see through the dwarf's eyes, it doesn't grant you any dwarven vision. If it granted you darkvision, it would say so.

Since magic items only do what they say they do and it doesn't say it grants darkvision: **no**, you aren't given darkvision when looking through its eyes.

Comment: What if the user had darkvision? Does they retain it while seeing through the head's eyes?

Comment: @enkryptor that sounds like an interesting question, deserving of a post. I doubt SSD will be answering it in comments, as that's not what comments are for.